# Cannot access Wireguard Server when switching the network

Tags: docker, nginx, raspberry-pi, vps, wireguard

I have the following setup:

A **VPS running wireguard and nginx (dockerized)**. My public domain points to the internal wireguard tunnel and is routed to my **RaspberryPi in my local network** (My raspberry runs wireguard acting as a client and homeassistant, also dockerized).

With that scenario, I can access my webpage, exposed from my pi, from anywhere. So far so good.

However, when I plug in the pi in a different network, I get the wireguard handshake but the webpage will only route to the correct endpoint and show a blank page (Chrome console says something about a ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR). On my network at home, I use an **LTE router** while my target network uses **Vodafone Cable**. That is the only difference that I can think of.

Does anyone have an idea, if I am overlooking something or if anyone had encountered something similar? I've read about different MTU sizes but I can't imagine that this might be the case. And also, with this setup I do NOT need any port-forwarding or port opening on the client-side.